# Comparing serial numbs to copy asset number to another column

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

```
      Asset1    Serial1   Serial2   AssetMatch2
Row1    [123    ser23     ser72     126
Row2    124     ser63     ser12     (blank)
Row3    125     ser72     ser63     124
Row4    126     ser19     ser10     (blank)]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAqJH.png

I am using Excel, I have tried using Match, and INDEX to try to accomplish this but nothing I do seems to format it correctly

I am trying to match "serial2" with "serial1" to then copy over "Asset1"'s corresponding asset value into the "assetMatch2" column for serial2

This would help by ensuring all serial numbers that are matching have the same asset tag number, If they do not match I would love to have a blank space that does not get filled.

Comment: what language or tools are you trying to accomplish this in?   what examples of your attempts can you post?

Comment: I am using Excel, I have been trying to use the if(index) and (match) commands but I can not seem to get it correct to copy correctly or match up the slightest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the upper left hand cell of your data is A1, copy this into cell E2 and fill down.

=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(D2,$C$1:$C$5,0)),0)

So for the above formula, it checks whether the serial number in Serial2 matches any serial number in Serial1. If so, it pulls the corresponding value from Asset1. If not, it will display zero using IFERROR.

Let me know if this was what you were trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much